# In zapier, I trigger using RSS. I want to add an extra pair in the raw data usig webhooks action

Tags: zapier

If I leave the data field empty, it will include the raw data from the previous step. Along with this raw data, I want to add an extra key value pair (say `'url' : 'www.zapier.com'`).

If I add it in the data field, I will only get that one pair.

I want the extra pair along with raw data.

Here is the raw data with the pair:

```
{
  "description": " ",
  "date": " ",
  "id": " 123 ",
  "url" : "www.zapier.com"    // <-- 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

It sounds like you're talking about the following line from the **Custom Request** action:

> If yes, request data below will be overridden with the raw data from the previous step

Unfortunately, it's either all the previous data or none of it (you can't modify it when doing a passthrough). The good news is, it's easy to create your own payload that combines the previous data and what you want to add. You can do that in a regular **POST** action like so:

[image]

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: I added an rss feed url in the TRIGGER step. I want to add that to my json payload packet in POST ACTION. Is it possible to retrieve that url from raw data or is there any other method?

Comment: You can't access input from a trigger in the input of an action. In most cases, that value is static (especially in a trigger, where that input can't be mapped from anywhere else), so hopefully you can also type it manually in the action